# Phonegap Build, HTML5 Audio, Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, phonegap-build

I'm developing this app for a local radio as part of community outreach type deal for my company (placement student) i kinda threw myself in at the deep end and decided to go with building this website -> app with only a tiny knowledge of the technologies i'm using however it's working quite well at the moment i'm just having a problem with the following.

So basically i'm trying to stream some audio using html audio tags. This works in my browser but not in my emulator (ripple emulator, nexus 4) nor on my android phone (HTC One).

Technologies - HTML5, CSS, Jquery Mobile and Phonegap Build.

I feel like i probably have to do something with Javascript.

```
    <audio controls>
    <source src="http://195.10.228.6:8035/canal.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: to clarify i am able to see the audio player and also interact with it, it either just won't play sound or it doesn't play the stream not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<audio id="stream" preload='none'>
        <source src="audio source" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>

<script>
var stream = document.getElementById('stream'),
ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

// Update the Button
var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

// Update the Audio
var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
stream[method]();

// Prevent Default Action
return false;
};
</script>
```

This code fixes most things it will allow you to play through your phone and also only has a play/pause link. you can do any styling you wish later on.

problems-takes about 10seconds prior to clicking play to load ~ atleast for my stream anyways for local files probably alot easier

Comment: Thank you!!!! I love you so much! It is only one possible way to play streaming in IOS+phonegap.

Comment: @Weltkind No problem, I never actually tried it on IOS so I'm glad to see it works there too.

Comment: does anyone can give some solution, how to decrease preload time? same code works well on ios and stream start after just a few seconds. but android version have delay about 10-15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You need to include more sound formats, as the MP3 isn't probably supported. According to http://html5please.com/#audio you have to include at least OGG and AAC formats.

Also beware that [Opera Mini does not support the audio tag at all](http://caniuse.com/audio). You should include a polyfill, some were mentioned in the first link (http://html5please.com/#audio).

Comment: Are you saying that for it to even attempt to run it would have to have different versions available or just that the current format probably doesn't run.

Comment: completely missed the whole polyfill part you were talking about. Are any of them capable of being used to stream a live radio show (thats what the stream is for) as i have seen that that can be a limitation of some players. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you are making a PhoneGap app, so the polyfill part is probably irrelevant...

Comment: Unfortunate, that looked promising for a second

Comment: Did including more formats help? If not, you can still try the polyfill: http://mediaelementjs.com/ and try if that helps. It uses Flash as fallback -- does PhoneGap support Flash?

Comment: right new problems well not problems, the stream will work fine on occasion this seems to happen whenever the html audio player sorta bugs out and no time slider appears, so it's just either play or pause anyway i can get it to only display that?

Comment: more updates. It works now extremely well however, you have to wait for about 10seconds just playing around with the app before you hit the play/pause button for it to work.then play/pause works perfectly.

Comment: That looks like an another problem. Close this question and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into adding your external site to the config.xml whitelist?

Documentation for this is available:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide